# Use Symbology of another shapefile within the same project

Tags: qgis, symbology

In ArcMap, I can go to Properties/Symbology and click on Import to use the symbolization of another shapefile within the same MXD. Is it possible to do the same thing in QGIS? Since I am importing several files that need the same symbolization (symbol, colors, etc) it is very time consuming to do it for every single shapefile.

Comment: @Erik please post your comment as an answer so this thread can be marked as solved

Answer (score 4):

Step 1: Set up a layer with the desired symbology.

Step 2: Right click that layer in the layer window, choose `styles - copy style - all style categories`.

[image]

Step 3: Mark all other layers which you want to look similar. Rightclick any of the marked layers and choose `paste style`.

[image]